# Frequently switching IP address

Tags: ip-address, vpn

I was trying to write a script to frequently switch my IP address. Does anyone know where I can start? Should I use VPN service? Is there any recommended US VPN service? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Private Internet access is a great VPN that has over 400 IPs and as many switches as you want a year.  Please let me know if you figure this script out, as I am working on the same project.

Good Luck!